# Throw new TypeError when Date is invalid Date object

Tags: javascript, date, typeerror

I need some help.. I need to make a throw new TypeError when my finishedDate is set to a invalid Date object except if it's undefined.
When I did it for my dueDate I wrote:

```
 Object.defineProperty(this, 'dueDate', {
get: function() {
  return _dueDate;
},
set: function(dueDate) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(dueDate) !== "[object Date]") {
    throw new TypeError('invalid date');
  }
  _dueDate = dueDate;
}
});
```

But when I try to do this for finishedDate it won't work because sometimes there is no finishedDate, it's undefined?

Comment: yes the code is dueDate as said in the text that's how I did to get the dueDate but it didn't work for finishedDate since finishedDate sometimes can be undefined (when the item is not finished).
the date should be 2016-10-09 and if it's set to something else it should throw a TypeError? So it's "protected" and can only be set to a valid Date object

Comment: I don't see any variable `finishedDate` anywhere in your code. Also, could you please indent your code properly?

Comment: Note that your test for an "invalid Date" fails, since an invalid Date is a valid Date object, e.g. `Object.prototype.toString.call(new Date('foo')) !== "[object Date]"` returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't throw the error if `finishedDate` is `undefined`:

```
set: function(finishedDate) {
    if (finishedDate !== undefined && Object.prototype.toString.call(finishedDate) !== "[object Date]") {
// -----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      throw new TypeError('invalid date');
    }
    _finishedDate = finishedDate;
}
```

Comment: maybe you could help me a bit more.. I need to make an isDone also where it should be read-only? 
It should return a value that indicates if the task is done?

Comment: @babyCoder: Okay, where are you stuck? You seem to know how to define properties with accessors (if you want it to be a property with an accessor rather that an explicit function call).

Comment: @crowder
I made this so far: `Object.definsProperty(this, 'isDone', {` 
`get: function() {` 
`return _isDone;` 
`}` 
`});` But what should I do after this if I want it to be able to return true and false? I shouldn't use a setter because it should throw an error if the isDone is set as it should be a "read-only"?